# Reduce Length of a string without losing data

Tags: java, string, reduce, radix, string-length

I have a string of length 13 composed of alphabets(uppercase +  lowercase both are possible but currently using only UpperCase) and Integers (0-9)(ex: BWOOL0JDXUNP1) and I wanted to reduce its length to 6-10 characters without losing any data.
I tried this by converting it into bytes using `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` then `new BigInteger(1, bytes).toString(36)` but it increases the length to 18 characters.
I am not sure if it is possible or not. If there is any way to do this in Java please help.

Comment: What characters is the string composed of?    Digits and uppercase letters only?

Comment: yes, currently I have used `ToUpperCase()` method

Comment: You could in theory use Run-length encoding (RLE). If there are enough repitions in your char sequence, it would compress your data. But there is no guarantee that it will reduce every string to a predefined length. So not sure if this helps.

Comment: What is of importance here. The length or the size?

Comment: Only alphabets? A-Z and 0-9?

Comment: @NicoVanBelle length is the factor here

Comment: @Darkman I have updated my question,
my string is composed of alphabets and integers.

Comment: Is it possible to encode it keeping the collision issue in mind, so that its length becomes smaller?

Comment: You are basically asking: how can I magically cut arbitrary ASCII strings in half, still representing them as ASCII strings, and do that reliably? That is in essence what you want. And no, if we could just look at any string and cut in half like that without losing information, that would be nice.

Comment: sorry, By "alphabets" I meant  A-Z and a-z.

Comment: If you want to reduce the length of a string, I think you're out of luck. But if you don't mind to convert it into a byte array (number of bytes is critical) then it is possible (Only for A-Z and 0-9).

Comment: did you try simple compression? https://xperti.io/blogs/java-string-data-compression-and-decompression/

Comment: Note: never put such new information into comments. Always [edit] your question instead. Don't expect other people to read through 20 comments to understand all the details needed to answer.

Comment: @MarcStroebel - Simple compression is unlikely to be very effective in a random string, especially a short one.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the string represents a number in base 36 `[0-9A-Z]`, it may be "compressed" additionally by converting to base 62 `[0-9A-Za-z]`, however, this does not help much in reducing the size, only 1 symbol is "saved":

```java
String str = "BWOOL0JDXUNP1";
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(str, 36);

String alpha = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
BigInteger size = BigInteger.valueOf(alpha.length());
System.out.println(str);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (bi.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) > 0) {
    int cp = bi.mod(size).intValue();
    sb.append(alpha.charAt(cp));
    bi = bi.divide(size);
}
System.out.println(sb);
// -> BWOOL0JDXUNP1
// -> NXew7nv28E51
```

Additionally, binary compression may be applied with some custom encoding, for instance, the mentioned 62 characters `[0-9A-Za-z]` fit into just 6 bits, so the mentioned 12 characters may be represented with just 12 * 0.75 = 9 bytes.  Of course, in this case additional "unpacking" method would be needed to properly represent the result.

Comment: Note that the OP mentioned an hour ago that the input strings are A-Z,a-z,0-9 ...

Comment: _...but currently using only UpperCase_ I assumed, that lowercase are accepted in the output

Comment: That is the reason why answering such questions always carries the risk of getting things wrong. "Assuming that you mean this or that" is very often an indication that you shouldnt write an answer, but close vote the question and suggest to the OP to clarify their input